# How to pull new docker images and restart docker containers after building docker images on gitlab?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

There is an `asp.net core api` project, with sources in `gitlab`.
Created `gitlab` `ci/cd pipeline` to build `docker` image and put the image into `gitlab` `docker` registry
(thanks to https://medium.com/faun/building-a-docker-image-with-gitlab-ci-and-net-core-8f59681a86c4).

How to update `docker containers` on my production system after putting the image to `gitlab` `docker registry`?

*by update I mean:

```
docker-compose down && docker pull && docker-compose up
```

Comment: did you mean `docker-compose pull`?

Comment: @HåkenLid, yes, how to do `docker-compose pull` automatically after new image creation, using gitlab ci. maybe stage deploy? But builder runner is a free gitlab-ci shared runner. To deploy I need local runner? Or It is better to use ssh deploy using shared runner. Or better to use webhooks with some other tool on my system side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use Image puller, lot of open sources are available, or you can write your own on the Shell. There is one [here](https://www.andreagrandi.it/2014/10/25/automatically-pull-updated-docker-images-and-restart-containers-with-docker-puller/). We use swarm, and we use this hook concept to be triggered from our CI-CD pipeline. Once our build stage is done, we http the hook url, and the docker pulls the updated image. 
 One disadvantage with this is you need a daemon to watch your hook task, that it doesnt crash or go down. So my suggestion is to run this hook task as a docker container with `restart-policy` as `RestartAlways`